# Ns2 Modify the source code and compile in ns2

Tags: tcl, ns2

I have been trying to modify the TCP source file parameters and I wanted to execute the modified source file in ns2. Can someone give the steps involved to modify and compile the code in ns2 and I am new in ns2.

Answer (score 0):

---

Source code is not used at simulation time. All functions are compiled into one file : The executable 'ns'.

Save your original 'ns' and make a backup copy = 'ns-orig'.

```
$ cd ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/
$ sudo make install ('make install' will copy 'ns' to /usr/local/bin/ns )
$ sudo cp ns-orig /usr/local/bin/
```

Building a modified 'ns' ( With your modified TCP ) :

```
$ cd ns-allinone-2.35/ && ./install
$ cd ns-2.35/
$ cp ns ns-modified
$ cp ns-modified /usr/local/bin/
```

... Then your new simulation can be done with `$ ns-modified [file].tcl`

---

---

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I just wanted to ask that if I change the default values  in the ns_default.tcl. Will it take the values that I have changed after executing these commands as I did but my output still remains the same. It would be of great help if you could tell me about this issue.